SharePoint - show Yes/No column from a lookup table
I have a list A which has columns ItemCode (text type) and Enabled (Yes/No type).
In list B I created a lookup column to list A. I am able to show in list B ItemCode from list A however I don't seem to be able to show the Enabled column from list A in list B.
As a workaround I created a third column in list A called EnabledText (calculated, text type) which shows 'Yes' or 'No' depending on the value from column Enabled.
This third column is available for selection in list B - I am able to show it list B. However it appears as text. Is there a way to show it as Yes/No column (with ticks/checkboxes)?

Your workaround (create another calculated column with text value Yes or No) is correct.
In fact, it is not possible to create a lookup column with a Yes/No field:

The following table summarizes the column types that can and can't be
used to create lookup columns.
Supported column types:

Single line of text

Number

Date and Time

Lookup (single value)


Unsupported column types:

Multiple lines of text

Choice

Calculated

Hyperlink or Picture

Custom Columns

Lookup (multi-valued)

Person

Yes/No

Currency



Source: Create list relationships by using lookup columns

Your question: This third column is available for selection in list B - I am able to show it list B. However it appears as text. Is there a way to show it as Yes/No column (with ticks/checkboxes)?
Answer:
Yes, it is possible to show a text column (with values Yes and No) with ticks/checkboxes using SharePoint JSON column formatting.
You have to use below JSON for your text column:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "padding-left": "15px"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "=if(@currentField == 'Yes','CheckboxComposite','Checkbox')",
        "class": "=if(@currentField == 'Yes','ms-fontColor-neutralPrimary','ms-fontColor-neutralTertiary')+' ms-fontSize-l'"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Steps to apply JSON column formatting: Use column formatting to customize SharePoint.
Output:

